# python: apply (math.sqrt ,(4)) returns "TypeError: apply() arg 2 expected sequence, found int"

Tags: python, apply

In python,

```
apply (math.sqrt ,(4))
```

(or other single argument functions)
returns

```
TypeError: apply() arg 2 expected sequence, found int
```

Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Note that the Python builtin `apply` is deprecated since Python 2.3, and has been removed in Python 3

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply):

```
the args argument must be a sequence.
```

`(4)` is not a sequence, it's just `4`. To make a length-1 tuple, use `(4,)`.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could also pass it a list with one item: apply(math.sqrt, [4])

Comment: Or even better: just call `math.sqrt(4)`.

Comment: This is in the bowels of  cross-compiler, sqrt is just one single argument example.  So clearly I need to do some sort of pattern recognition and rewrite the term anyway.  I think that it will be easier to just prefix the last paren with a comma.  THanks again.